# sql, вывод данных в две колонки

Tags: sql

есть устройство отпечатки пальцев фирмы ZKTECO, работник утром приходит заносит запись, вечером уходит так же заносит запись в базу данных, так вот эти записи идут в одной колонке последовательно , устройство почему-то не заносить записи отдельно, мне необходимо вывести запись о приходе сотрудника в одной колонке выход в другой, как это можно будет реализовать ?
данные в таблице выглядит следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169) + [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример решения задачи (модель):

```
CREATE TABLE test (userid INT, checktime DATETIME, checktype CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '2022-02-01 01:00:00', 'I'),
(1, '2022-02-02 01:00:00', 'I'),
(1, '2022-02-03 01:00:00', 'I'),
(1, '2022-02-04 01:00:00', 'O'),
(1, '2022-02-05 01:00:00', 'O'),
(1, '2022-02-06 01:00:00', 'I'),
(1, '2022-02-07 01:00:00', 'O'),
(1, '2022-02-08 01:00:00', 'I'),
(1, '2022-02-09 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-01 01:00:00', 'I'),
(2, '2022-02-02 01:00:00', 'I'),
(2, '2022-02-03 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-04 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-05 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-06 01:00:00', 'I'),
(2, '2022-02-07 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-08 01:00:00', 'I'),
(2, '2022-02-09 01:00:00', 'I'),
(2, '2022-02-10 01:00:00', 'O'),
(2, '2022-02-11 01:00:00', 'I');
```

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE WHEN checktype = 'O' 
               AND LAG(checktype) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY checktime) = 'I'
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1 END is_pair
  FROM test
  ),
cte2 AS ( 
  SELECT *, 
        SUM(is_pair) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY checktime) pair_no
  FROM cte1
  )
SELECT userid, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN checktype = 'I' THEN checktime END) time_in,
       MAX(CASE WHEN checktype = 'O' THEN checktime END) time_out
FROM cte2
GROUP BY userid, pair_no
ORDER BY userid, pair_no
;
```

| userid | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 01:00:00.000 | *null* |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 01:00:00.000 | *null* |
| 1 | 2022-02-03 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-04 01:00:00.000 |
| 1 | *null* | 2022-02-05 01:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-07 01:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 2022-02-08 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-09 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 01:00:00.000 | *null* |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-03 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | *null* | 2022-02-04 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | *null* | 2022-02-05 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-06 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-07 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-08 01:00:00.000 | *null* |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 01:00:00.000 | 2022-02-10 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-11 01:00:00.000 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SrV71G6X)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CIO AS
(
SELECT  UserId
        ,CheckType
        ,CheckTime
        ,CASE WHEN LEAD(CheckType) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CheckTime) = 'O'
        THEN LEAD(CheckTime) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY CheckTime) END AS ExitTime
FROM zktecodb.dbo.CheckInOut
)
SELECT UserId, CheckTime AS EntryTime, ExitTime
FROM CIO
WHERE CheckType = 'I'
```

Comment: меня это устраивает, только в sql ошибку выдает  `Ошибка преобразования значения varchar "I" в тип данных int.
`

Comment: выводит записи , только графа OutTime пусто, еще не все записи выводит, может выложит изображение с результатом запроса ?

Comment: @jun66 я там ошибся изначально, сейчас поправил. Попробуйте ещё раз